# What is the target audience of this site?

Tags: discussion

Is this site for anyone using elementary or is it aimed at more non-technical users? Or another demographic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this site is aimed at anyone seeking assistance with any elementary-specific problem. Unfortunately, you then inherit the targeting of elementary OS, which is primarily downloaded by Windows and OS X users. As a result, I think we can conclude that many of these users will be less technically adept.

Comment: ahh, that explains a lot... This is a very different audience to most Linux OSes...

Comment: @user3 not quite true. In the "old days" (the not necessarily good old days) most Linux users were technically advanced. These days, Linux is the base of many fully fledged desktop operating systems, and used by many technical novices. If you check most of the questions on U&L and Ask Ubuntu, for example, you'll find that there is a good mixture, with deeper level tech-genius type questions being a little more rare than one might think - coming from the "old school". It's leading to an improvement of the ecosystem that has been too long in coming.